# 1 commit to 2 branches - what does it mean?

Tags: git

I wanted to check commits to a branch, and I saw that there were commits that appear in 2 branches.

Why?
What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@matisa consider *git* as a tree which grows with each new commit and branch.
Each branch can itself have many commits and child branches which means adjacents branches will always share a common ancestry.

Now *git* can merge any child branch in any of its ancestors, this does not mean you will lose those intermediate commits since every commit is logged which means we always have a list of all the previous commits and when we can merge any head (child branch) to say in its grandparent.

```
A -> A|B -> AB|C  (merging C in A)
ABC -> A|B ( merged C in A)
```

*git* takes all of those commits which were not present in its grandparent branch which are the commits of child + commits of the parent.

Which leads to the same commit history amongst two branches. So, it is pretty common for branches to have the same commit in their history

I strongly recommend you to read about git [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1)

Comment: So, basically it is a result of a merge?

Comment: @matisa merge could be one of the reason, most likely it branches sharing same commit history due to merge

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have deleted the `non-QA branch` in the end after merging and that is why it shows that there is only one existing branch (`QA`) in the end. You, or someone else, might also deleted their `non-QA` branch in the third to last commit after merging with `QA`.